# How to convert all file characters to uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: c++

I tried to take every character in a file and use with `toupper()` and `tolower()` functions. But I can't put the result instead of the character.

I used a `vector` to solve it.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

```
void UpperCase(){
    fstream file;
    char name[81] , ch;
    vector<char> container;
    cout << "Enter the file name : ";
    cin >> name;
    file.open(name,ios::in);
    while(!file.eof() && !file.fail()){
        file.get(ch);
        container.push_back(toupper(ch));
    }
    file.close();
    file.open(name,ios::out);
    for(int i=0 ; i<container.size()-1 ; ++i){
        file.put(container[i]);
    }
    file.close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Somewhere, I'm sure code was involved. We're rather poor mind readers. [Post the code **in your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49499489/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an efficient method:

```
char buffer[4096];
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter filename: ";
std::cin >> name;
std::ifstream input(name.c_str(), ios::binary);
const std::string out_filename = name + ".upper_case";
std::ofstream output(out_filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
while (input.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))
{
  const unsigned int chars_read = input.gcount();
  std::transform(&buffer[0], &buffer[chars_read],
                 &buffer[0], toupper);
  output.write(buffer, chars_read);
}
```

The above code reads in a block of characters, then transforms them to uppercase, then writes the block to another file.

Writing to another file is a safe practice, and you don't need to read the entire file into memory.

You can change the size of the buffer to make the program more efficient.  Recommend sizes are multiples of 512, since that is a standardized size for a hard drive sector.

**Edit 1:**
If you are allergic to `std::transform`, replace the call with a loop to convert the characters.

Comment: Note that the buffer is not toupper compliant, as per: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper

Comment: Yes, `toupper` wants a `int` as its parameter and the buffer is `char`.

Comment: The buffer should be `unsigned char`.